# javafx tablecolumn is not showing anything if all values are null?

Tags: java, javafx-2, tableview, tablecell, tablecolumn

I am working with javafx tableview.

One of my column is currently having all row as null but I still want it to display it by having null written in those columns.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setCellFactory() and on the updateItem() methode, you check if item is null and if it's true you write "null"

```
@Override
public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (item == null || empty) {
        setText("null");
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
       //Things to do if it's not null
    }
}
```

check that for detail http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/customcellfactory.htm but for display null just do what I say

Comment: but it also has some update and a null value might change from null to non null so how to handle it in that case...

Comment: if you change the value of a cell, so in the next updateItem, you will be in the case where item != null, so you juste need to do what you want with the non null value.